# Adding page (menu item) in Wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a new page to the admin area of Wordpress using the `admin_menu` action, but it is not working:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'laksh_advert_menu');
function laksh_advert_menu() { 
  add_menu_page( 
      'Advert', 
      'Advert', 
      'edit_posts', 
      'advert', 
      'laksh_advert_page', 
      'dashicons-admin-tools'
     );
}

function laksh_advert_page() {
    echo "Hello";
}
```

Comment: I have checked your source code in my wordpress test version. It's working fine for me. what kind of problems you are facing? Any errors or something.???

Comment: @AnkitPanchal There is no error, when I load the admin area, my new menu item simply won't show on the menu. And yes, I also tested with another wp install, and this code works fine. FYI, my user role is Admin, so I should see the menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You trying add position and change capability menu:

```
function laksh_advert_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 
        __( 'Advert', 'textdomain' ),
        'advert menu',
        'manage_options',
        'advert',
        'laksh_advert_page',
        'dashicons-admin-tools',
       10
    ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'laksh_advert_menu' );

function laksh_advert_page(){
    esc_html_e( 'Admin Page Test', 'textdomain' );  
}
```

I think some a plugin external can that write your position or manager your menus, but trying "pin up" your menu position.

You have some plugin for menu?